# Why is my page speed so slow on developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Is there some simple things I can do to further speed up my site?

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yes.education%2F

I am only using sites.google.com and I have an analytics tag on the website. I also had my images optimized on the home page to a very low size, so I am puzzled that google would penalize me for using their own products.

Comment: The report page has straightforward recommendations (such as _deferring offscreen images_ and using `Cache-Control` headers for static resources). What part of the report are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you should jump over to the help centre and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then try and focus your question to one problem only. As @Dai said the PSI report lists everything you need to do to speed up your site under "daignostics" and "opportunities". You can click on each item to get more info and they all link to pages that explain each section. After that if you have a specific question about how to fix on issue please ask it here and we will be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I meant to add that I am only using sites.google.com and I have an analytics tag on the website.  I also had my images optimized on the home page to a very low size, so I am puzzled that google would penalize me for using their own products.

Comment: How can use Cache-Control if I am using sites.google.com for my website?